# What is the relationship betwen covariance, covariance matrix and cross-correlation?

Tags: python, covariance, covariance-matrix, cross-correlation

I am not good at math and apologize if I made stupid mistakes in this question.

Assume I have two random variables X = [1, 2, 7, 3, 0, 10 ...] and Y = [12, 1, 5, 7, 9, ...].

According to the definition, cov(X,Y)=E[(X-E[Y])(Y-E[Y])] = E[XY]-E[X][Y], so it looks like a scalar to me, which measures how X is related to Y. If I am writing a python script to calculate it, it will be like:

```
import numpy as np
X = [1, 2, 7, 3, 0, 10]
Y = [12, 1, 5, 7, 9, 4]
X=np.asarray(X)
Y=np.asarray(Y)
cov = (X*Y).mean()-X.mean()*Y.mean()
print(cov)  
# output is -5.944444444444446
```

But if I use numpy.cov(X,Y), it returns a 2 x 2 matrix:

```
import numpy as np
X = [1, 2, 7, 3, 0, 10]
Y = [12, 1, 5, 7, 9, 4]
c = np.cov(X,Y, rowvar = True)
print(c)
# output is [[14.96666667 -7.13333333]
            [-7.13333333 15.06666667]]
```

How should I interpret the above 2x2 matrix?

I guess, if I treat X and Y as two time sequenes, I can calculate cross correlation like this:

```
print(np.correlate(X,Y))
# output is 110
```

So my questions are:
(1) How cross-corrlation is related to just covariance, if X and Y can be seen as time sequences?
(2) According to the above case, what is the relation between my calculated scalar value and the 2x2 matrix obtained from numpy.cov(x,y)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.cov` function returns you a covariance matrix, where off-diagonal entries are covariances and diagonal entries are variances. The covariance estimate of `np.cov` is [unbiased](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) (check `bias` argument), which means the normalisation is done with $N-1$, here $5$, since there are $6$ observations. It'd be $-7.13\times 6/5\approx -5.94$ if it was normalised by $N=6$. That is precisely what you do while you're taking *means* in your implementation. Also, `np.correlate` with default arguments apparently calculates the dot product of the vectors.